# Drupal 7 - How to use objects

Tags: php, object, drupal-7

I'm trying to figure out how to leverage drupals native functions to copy a folder to a destination. I've found the class called [FileTransfer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--filetransfer.inc/function/FileTransfer%3a%3acopyDirectory/7), which has a method called copyDirectory. The problem is that the FileTransfer class is abstract and I can't figure out how to reach that method.

Here's the code I'm using

```
<?php
function generator_form_submit($form, $form_state) {

  $modules_folder = 'sites/all/modules/custom/';
  $model_folder = drupal_get_path('module', 'generator') . '/model';

  class transfer {
    function copy() {
      FileTransfer::copyDirectory($model_folder, $modules_folder);
    }
  }

  $transfer = new transfer;
  $transfer->copy($model_folder, $modules_folder);
}
?>
```

This throws me the error "Call to undefined method transfer::sanitizePath()", since the method uses $this. I've tried many ways to get it working, but the code I'm posting here is the best attempt I've got.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileTransfer` class is an abstract class specifying what is required to perform a file transfer, it can't actually perform one itself without a subclass implementing various methods. Drupal provides the subclasses [`FileTransferFTP`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--ftp.inc/class/FileTransferFTP/7), [`FileTransferLocal`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--local.inc/class/FileTransferLocal/7) and [`FileTransferSSH`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--ssh.inc/class/FileTransferSSH/7), which *I believe* are non-abstract. You probably should use whichever of these is appropriate.